# OpenTk - How to Enable Multisampling

Tags: c#, opengl, antialiasing, opentk, multisampling

I'm trying to implement multisampling in OpenTK but when i enable it there's no diffrence between 
no antyaliasing and multisampling.

[No Antyaliasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SXOQ.png)

[image: No Antyaliasing]

[Multisampling Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEiCb.png)

[image: Multisampling Enabled]

Here's a code in OnRenderFrame for multisampling :

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.AccumBufferBit);

        shaders[activeShader].EnableVertexAttribArrays();

        int indiceat = 0;
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Multisample);
        GL.Hint(HintTarget.MultisampleFilterHintNv,HintMode.Nicest);
        foreach (Volume v in objects)
        {
            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, v.TextureID);
            GL.UniformMatrix4(shaders[activeShader].GetUniform("modelview"), false, ref v.ModelViewProjectionMatrix);

            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, v.IndiceCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, indiceat * sizeof(uint));
            indiceat += v.IndiceCount;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to create a window with a multisample buffer, by setting the [`GraphicsMode`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode.html). Set the `GraphicsMode` when the [`GameWindow`](https://opentk.net/api/OpenTK.GameWindow.html) is constructed:

e.g.:

```cs
public class OpenTK_Window
    : GameWindow
{
    OpenTK_Window(int width, int height, string title)
        : base(width, height, new GraphicsMode(32, 24, 8, 8), title,
    {}

    // [...]
}
```

In this case the 4th parameter to the constructor of `GraphicsMode` is the number of samples.

Comment: I thought for a second you were wrong, because it wouldnt let me turn it off. 
But if i want to start without antialiasing i needed to disable it in rendering without it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have such a thing like `GraphicsMode` In OpenTK 5.0 everything changed =(